# Redis delete batch keys strips slashes from key names

Tags: redis, xargs, redis-cli

In my MacOs 10.15 environment I have a strange Redis behaviour when I list some keys with:

```
redis-cli -n 1 --scan --pattern "product_doctrine*"
```

It gives me for example:

```
product_doctrine[AppBundle\Entity\ColumnMapping\$GEDMO_TIMESTAMPABLE_CLASSMETADATA][21546]
```

But It doesn’t delete it using xargs:

```
redis-cli -n 1 --scan --pattern "product_doctrine*" | xargs -L 1 redis-cli -n 1 del
(integer) 0
```

Is it maybe of the key name having special characters? Because if I run this inide the redis-cli:

```
SCAN 0 MATCH product_doctrine*
```

it shows the keys with escaped antislash:

`"product_doctrine[AppBundle\\Entity\\ShopSettings\\$GEDMO_SOFTDELETEABLE_CLASSMETADATA][11677]"`

Inside `redis-cli` I can delete those kind of keys successfully with

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> del "product_doctrine[AppBundle\\Entity\\ShopSettings\\$GEDMO_SOFTDELETEABLE_CLASSMETADATA][11677]"
(integer) 1
```

Comment: Which OS are you on? Specifically, which `xargs`? Note that per its man page, `xargs` treats backslashes differently. This, combined with the shell's and redis-cli's quirks leads to your experience.

Comment: I run it on a MacOs 10.15 environment

Answer (score 0):

On macOS 10.14 the following does it:

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern "foo*" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/' | xargs -L 1 redis-cli DEL
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯